# Do experience points in 5e continue to stack or do they get expended and leave carry over points towards the next level?

Tags: dnd-5e, experience-points

I run two campaigns and decided to run them differently based on the PC desires.  In the combat-heavy war-torn campaign I expend all points except those over the leveling up threshold to make it longer and tougher thereby giving the players more combat.  The narrative heavy campaign I have been maintaining the accumulation of all XP so as to make it more fun because they wanted to find items and combat isn't such a high priority.  Both groups have decided they want to join forces and create a single campaign but I can't until I can make them close to equals so I wondered which version is the correct ruling.

Comment: I though we already had the question on the site, but it turned out that the question I was remembering [is for 4th edition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25882). So, good first question, and welcome!

Answer (score 13):

### XP continues to stack.

PHB 12 states,

> Also record your experience points. A 1st-level character has 0
>   XP. A higher-level character typically begins with the minimum amount of XP required to reach that level (see “Beyond 1st Level” later in this chapter).

If XP reset after each level, then a 1st-level character and a higher level character would both start with 0 XP.

You might have noticed that under this system, the XP curve is a little weird because characters level up a lot faster after level 10. However, this is intentional ([from a designer tweet](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/619616658584264705)):

> it's an intentional bump - higher levels are meant to move a little faster than first 10

There's some more discussion of this issue at [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/why-does-the-experience-to-next-level-not-change-between-some-levels).

Comment: For that last point it's probably worth also linking to our Q, [Why does the experience-to-next-level not change between some levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62346)

Answer (score 7):

XP accumulate throughout the "life" of the character - they only ever go up, they never go down.

A character's level is known by looking up their total XP in the table.

Comment: There are some exceptions, like the (Idiot?) card in the Deck Of Many Things, but in general this is accurate.